# Bi-variant interactive function plotting using IPython

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I want to plot two functions, say sine and cosine, with different frequencies --- so the first variable is the function to plot and the second is it frequency. I want to have a selector widget that selects the function and a slider that chooses the frequency. Is it possible to achieve this using `interact` or do I need a more complicated setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this should be possible with `interact` For further reading there are a couple of [`example notebooks`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/tree/master/examples/Interactive%20Widgets) in the github repository that can be used as an introduction into interactive widgets.

```
%matplotlib inline
from IPython.html import widgets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fun_map = {
    "sin": np.sin,
    "cos": np.cos
}

func_name = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['sin', 'cos'],
    value='sin',
    description='Function:',
)

freq = widgets.FloatSlider(
    min=1,
    max=5,
    value=1,
    description='Parameter:'
)

def plot_fun(func_name, freq, fun_map):
    f = fun_map[func_name]
    x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    plt.plot(x, f(freq * x))

res = widgets.interact(plot_fun, freq=freq, func_name=func_name,
                       fun_map=widgets.fixed(fun_map))
```

This is the result:

[image: result]

Comment: This IS what I was looking for. Where is it documented? Can you please add some links?

Comment: @Dror, I added a link to `ipython`'s example notebooks. AFAIK, there is not a comprehensive documentation yet. Yet, one can learn a lot from those notebooks.